# Sequence in weak and weak* topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

I try to find the example to show this

> If $f_{n}\overset{w*}{\rightarrow} f$ and $x_{n}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}x$ not necessarily $f_{n}(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$.

prove the $f_{n}(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$ in the case $x_{n}\overset{||.||}{\rightarrow}x$ is so easy but find the example for the another case is hard for me.

Comment: Look at the standard unit vectors in $c_0$ and $\ell_1$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you .

Comment: As a footnote: a Banach space $X$ is said to have property DP* if $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$ whenever $f_n\to f$ weak* in $X^*$ and $x_n\to x$ weakly in $X$. (see Definition 1.1 in https://doi.org/10.4064/sm184-3-1)